# Making a draggable UIView that snaps to edges in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, draggable

I'm trying to make a UIView that can be dragged around the screen, and when released will snap to the nearest edge.

I've got the dragging sorted out - I'm using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer and when it's state is ended I'm calling the following method, where point is the longPressGestureRecognizer's locationInView, and rect is the UIView that contains both the gesturerecognizer and the draggable UIView. This method returns a CGPoint, which I then set to be the draggable UIView's center.

```
- (CGPoint)closestPointForPoint:(CGPoint)point toSnapToInRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGPoint closestPoint = point;

/// Left/Right

if ((point.x - rect.origin.x) > (rect.size.width - point.x)) {

    /// Point is closer to right side of frame, update the closestPoint's x.

    closestPoint.x = rect.size.width - (self.draggableView.frame.size.width / 2) - draggableViewMargin;
}
else {
    /// Point is closer to left side of frame, update the closestPoint's x.
    closestPoint.x = rect.origin.x + (self.draggableView.frame.size.width / 2) + draggableViewMargin;
}


/// Top/Bottom

if ((point.y - rect.origin.y) > (rect.size.height - point.y)) {
    /// Point is closer to top of frame, update the closestPoint's y.

    closestPoint.y = rect.size.height - (self.draggableView.frame.size.height / 2) - draggableViewMargin;
}
else {

    /// Point is closer to bottom of frame, update the closestPoint's y.
    closestPoint.y = rect.origin.y + (self.draggableView.frame.size.height / 2) + draggableViewMargin;

}

return closestPoint;
```

}

This works except that when I let go of the view it snaps to the nearest corner. This is nice but not what I'd like exactly. I want it to snap to the nearest edge, so for example if I let go of the view when its point is x: 50 y:100 (in a superview of 1136 x 640) I want it to snap to the left side (as the x value is smaller) but be 100 pixels down instead of the corner.

Could someone show me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that You and finding whether to snap to the left or right right and whether to snap up or down. What you are looking for is an algorithm to decide to snap either right, left, top or bottom.

Here is my solution:

```
//put all of the distances between the point and rect edges in an array.
NSArray *values = @[@(point.x - rect.origin.x), @(rect.size.width - point.x), @(point.y - rect.origin.y), @(rect.size.height - point.y)];

//Find the smallest distance.
NSNumber *minimumValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSIntegerMax];
for(NSNumber *value in values){
    if([value intValue] < [minimumValue intValue]){
        minimumValue = value;
    }
}

if([minimumValue intValue] == point.x - rect.origin.x){
    //snap to the left
}
if([minimumValue intValue] == rect.size.width - point.x){
    //snap to the right
}
if([minimumValue intValue] == point.y - rect.origin.y){
    //snap to the top
}
if([minimumValue intValue] == rect.size.height - point.y){
    //snap to the bottom
}
```

It puts all of the values (top margin, right margin...) in an array and iterates through them finding the smallest value. You can write the implementations for the `if` statements.  I've commented each for you. I hope this helps you out.

**Edit:**

I've updated the code and fixed some errors. It worked for me when I tested it out.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but sadly it did not work - it tends to either meet none of the conditions or only the last one (I believe you had a typo; I used if([minimumValue intValue] == rect.size.height - point.y)) but I think this is still a better approach than my own, I'll try some things based on this and get back to you.

Comment: @mMo I took another look at the code today and fixed some problems with it. It worked perfectly when I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

This answer doesn't work for me, maybe I confuse the `rect` and `point`

I have a another solution, and it requires no loop, just need some equations check.

1. First, divide the screen into four areas. I can't post images now due to lack of reputation, the script paper is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Mos.jpg
2. Then, write down the formulas of the lines in the dimensional coordinate system
3. Last, List the equations of each area, now you can just replace the x y in the equations with end point's x y.

   ```
   CGPoint endPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
   CGFloat k = self.view.bounds.size.height / self.view.bounds.size.width;
   CGFloat b = self.view.bounds.size.height;

   if (endPoint.y < k * endPoint.x && endPoint.y < -1 * k * endPoint.x + b) {
       NSLog(@"top edge");
   } else if (endPoint.y <= k * endPoint.x && endPoint.y >= -1 * k * endPoint.x + b) {
       NSLog(@"right edge");
   } else if (endPoint.y > k * endPoint.x && endPoint.y > -1 * k * endPoint.x + b) {
       NSLog(@"bottom edge");
   } else if (endPoint.y > k * endPoint.x && endPoint.y < -1 * k * endPoint.x + b) {
       NSLog(@"left edge");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should try and apply snapping for just one direction, either x or y; maybe something like this could work:

```
- (CGPoint)closestPointForPoint:(CGPoint)point toSnapToInRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGPoint closestPoint = point;

/// Left/Right

if (MIN(point.x - rect.origin.x, rect.size.width - point.x) < MIN(point.y - rect.origin.y, rect.size.height - point.y)) {

  if ((point.x - rect.origin.x) > (rect.size.width - point.x)) {

    /// Point is closer to right side of frame, update the closestPoint's x.

    closestPoint.x = rect.size.width - (self.draggableView.frame.size.width / 2) - draggableViewMargin;
  }
  else {
    /// Point is closer to left side of frame, update the closestPoint's x.
    closestPoint.x = rect.origin.x + (self.draggableView.frame.size.width / 2) + draggableViewMargin;
  }

} else {
/// Top/Bottom

  if ((point.y - rect.origin.y) > (rect.size.height - point.y)) {
    /// Point is closer to top of frame, update the closestPoint's y.

    closestPoint.y = rect.size.height - (self.draggableView.frame.size.height / 2) - draggableViewMargin;
  }
  else {

    /// Point is closer to bottom of frame, update the closestPoint's y.
    closestPoint.y = rect.origin.y + (self.draggableView.frame.size.height / 2) + draggableViewMargin;

  }
}

return closestPoint;
}
```